# Can't read an Excel file - File.open isn't valid

Tags: c#, .net, excel, file, file-upload

I'm building a small website in .NET with C#. The user has to upload an Excel file, extension .xls or .xlsx, that's already implemented. Though I'm having trouble actually reading the values from the Excel file. I currently have this piece of code written out:

```
    public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {            
            string fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            if (fileName.EndsWith(".xlsx") || (fileName.EndsWith(".xls")))
            {
                // store the file inside ~/App_Data/uploads folder
                string path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads/"), fileName);
                file.SaveAs(path);
                // Get file info
                int contentLength = file.ContentLength;
                string contentType = file.ContentType;

                // Get file data
                byte[] data = new byte[] { };
                using (var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(file.InputStream))
                {
                    data = binaryReader.ReadBytes(file.ContentLength);
                }

                using (FileStream fs = File.Open(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
                {
                    UTF8Encoding temp = new UTF8Encoding(true);

                    while (fs.Read(data, 0, data.Length) > 0)
                    {
                        //Console.WriteLine(temp.GetString(b));
                    }
                }

                // redirect back to the index action to show the form once again
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
```

Now I'm guessing the code aint bad, but I'm getting an error @ the second using line, at 'File.Open(...)'

```
'System.Web.Mvc.Controller.File(byte[], string)' is a 'method', which is not valid in the given context C:\Users\.....cs
```

I've read countless examples online, but none of them seem to have a similar problem :/ If anyone could solve this error or help me with this problem, it'd be much appreciated! It's probably something small/stupid.

Comment: Looks like there is a method called `File` in the MVC controller class. Try using a fully qualified name instead, i.e. `System.IO.File.Open(...)`.

Comment: It looks like you aren't importing the `System.IO` namespace. Also, trying to read an Excel file without a library like Aspose or Office Automation (which shouldn't be used in server-side applications anyway) is a Fool's Errand.

Comment: ah yes, that solved the error. Thanks! 
Also what would you recommend exactly? I'll google Aspose and OA, though I'm having a bit of trouble atm tbh.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your controller class is inheriting from System.Web.Mvc.Controller which has a method on the base class called File.  You'll need to explicitly use the correct statement in your using:

```
using (FileStream fs = System.IO.File.Open(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
```